# Why are my dropdown links not functioning in desktop view?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on a responsive website. In desktop view, the icon furthest to the right ("dropdown-btn") triggers a dropdown menu for contact-links. For some reason, the links are not responding as links. I'm not sure why...

live site:
https://georgeluther.github.io/Responsive-Flex-Hamburger-Form/

Answer (score 0):

You have `position: fixed` on your main navigation on the left and this lines up with the drop-down.

As you have not specified a width for the `<ul>` that holds these links they take up the whole width of the page. Because they appear later in the DOM they appear in front of your `<header>` which is also `position: fixed`.

Simple fix is to specify a width for your `<ul id="anchor-links">` so they don't spill out onto the page.